# limit of $\lim_{x\rightarrow1^-}{(1-x)^{\ln(x)}}$ with L'Hospital's rule

Tags: limits

How can one find the lim of the following function using L'Hospital's rule:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow1^-}{(1-x)^{\ln(x)}}$

I tried to use the exponent trick:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow1^-}{e^{\ln(x) \ln(1-x)}}$

and then solve:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow1^-}{\ln(x) \ln(1-x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow1^-}{\frac{\ln(x)}{\frac{1}{\ln(1-x)}}}=\frac{0}{0}$

But using L'Hospital's rule here gives no result and I'm stuck.

Anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute $t=1-x\to0^+$ as $x\to 1^-$. The limit becomes
$$\lim_{t\to0^+}t^{\ln(1-t)}=e^{\lim_{t\to0^+}\left(\ln(t)\ln(1-t)\right)} $$
using the continuity of $e^y$, and then use the basic limit $\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+y)}{y}=1$ (you can show it with L'Hopital's rule):
$$\lim_{t\to0^+}(\ln(t)\ln(1-t))=\lim_{t\to0^+}\left(-t\ln(t)\frac{\ln(1-t)}{-t}\right)=\lim_{t\to0^+}(-t\ln(t))=0 $$
For the last limit, apply L'Hospital's rule once: $\lim_{t\to 0^+}t\ln(t)=\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{\ln(t)}{\frac 1t}$.